# Mirror expression

Tags: constraints, drivers, properties

How can I rewrite an expression?

I have this expression written by Leander

```
min(1, max(0, Rest - CL) / max(0.001, FL-CL)) * 0.1
```

It drives a variable bone from 0 to 0.1  using to other bones as variables.

[image]

You can see my original post which was solved by Leander

[Driving average values with limits in blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/297046/driving-average-values-with-limits-in-blender)

I changed his code alittle by replacing the self.bone matrix. to a variable bone called "Rest" so that I can rotate the armature and hopefully have all the drivers follow along. However after parenting the bones to the big bone in edit mode  i rotate the bone and i get a result where once the bones rotation reaches 180 degrees the bones withthe drivers applied suddenly change position. this is very much undesired

[image]

So can anyone suggest a way to stop the drivers from moving once they pass the -/+ threshold. I have tried some absolute pythin expression namely

```
min(1, max(0, abs(Rest) - CL) / max(0.001, FL - CL)) * 0.1 <br>
 min(1, max(0, abs(Rest) - abs(CL)) / max(0.001, abs(FL) - abs(CL))) * 0.1
```

but to no avail. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]